# How to set MongoClient connection timeout?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a server which first connects to MongoDB instance, then starts web server. If MongoDB instance is not available, there is no point to start web server, so I think I need to somehow set a timeout to, say 5 seconds.

How do I do it?

Here is my code:

```
MongoClient.connect(Config.database.url).then((db) => {
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
        databaseInstance = db;
       // start web server
    })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use "connectTimeoutMS" like so

```
MongoClient.connect(Config.database.url, {
    server: {
        socketOptions: {
            connectTimeoutMS: 5000
        }
    }
}).then((db) => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
    databaseInstance = db;
   // start web server
})
```

Here is more information about it...

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/reference/connecting/connection-settings/
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html

Comment: I don't actually think this is what the OP wants (despite them marking it as accepted). **`connectTimeoutMS` isn't what most people would consider the connection timeout.** See @Ricky's answer below.

Answer (score 14):

- To define the timeout for the *initial* connection use `serverSelectionTimeoutMS`.
- To define the timeout for the *ongoing* connection `connectTimeoutMS`

MongoDB 3.6 connection example:

```js
const client = new MongoClient(Config.database.url, {
  connectTimeoutMS: 5000,
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000
})

client.connect(err => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB')
  // ..
})
```

See the [official docs for `serverSelectionTimeoutMS`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I (and I suspect OP, despite marking the other answer as correct) was looking for. `connectTimeoutMS` wasn't timing out the initial connection. `serverSelectionTimeoutMS` is exactly what we want.

Comment: `serverSelectionTimeoutMS` specifies how long (in milliseconds) to block for server selection before throwing an exception - it is not just for the initial connection as implied in this answer