# Why is my dockerized nodejs server not able to connect to my dockerized mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a mongodb docker container which is working correctly. I can query it from outside docker using localhost if I expose port 27017. I can query it from a python docker container on the same docker network using the mongo container name.

I also have a nodejs server in a docker container. It is on the same docker network as the mongodb container. If I create a simple test script and place it in the nodejs container, I am able to run it inside the nodejs container and successfully query the mongo container using the mongo containers name.

On a separate server, it I check out the project (identical code to where the problem is happening) and run "docker-compose up", the nodejs container is able to query the mongo container.

However, when running the project locally, the nodejs server code fails to connect to mongo using the container name. I constantly get the error "Connection to database failed, MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [sciencedog_db:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection timed out]".

Can anyone give me any ideas regarding what to look for? The error seems clear enough, but a test script makes it clear that there is in fact connectivity between the containers. Is there any way that a node server could be configured that would make the connection to the mongo container fail when the network is working? Is there some environmental factor I am missing?

Test script which works when run directly with node:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

// Replace the uri string with your MongoDB deployment's connection string.
const uri =
//   "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@<cluster-url>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    "mongodb://sciencedog_db:27017";

const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();

    const database = client.db('sciencedog');
    const collection = database.collection('users');

    // // Query for a movie that has the title 'Back to the Future'
    const query = { username: 'daniel' };
    const user = await collection.findOne(query);

    console.log(user);
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

Code in nodejs server which fails (part of a larger module), application is run with gulp:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

const host = process.env.MODE === 'development' ? 'localhost' : 'sciencedog_db'
const dbUrl = `mongodb://${host}:27017`
const dbName = 'sciencedog'

var db_client
function getConnection() {
    /**
     * Get a connection to the database.
     * @return {MongoClient} Connection to the database
     */
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (typeof db_client == 'undefined') {
            console.log("There is no db_client");
            MongoClient.connect(dbUrl).then(
                function (client) {
                    console.log("So we got one");
                    db_client = client
                    console.log("Connected successfully to server");
                    resolve(db_client)
                },
                function (err) {
                    let err_msg = 'Connection to database failed, ' + err
                    console.log(err_msg);
                    reject(err_msg)
                }
            )
        } else {
            console.log('Found existing database connection');
            resolve(db_client)
        }
    })
}
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    sciencedog_python:
        build: .
        container_name: sciencedog_python
        init: true
        stop_signal: SIGINT
        environment:
            - 'PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE'
        networks:
            - sciencedog
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
            - 8443:8443
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: /etc/sciencedog/.env
              target: /etc/sciencedog/.env
              read_only: true
            - type: bind
              source: .
              target: /opt/python_sciencedog/

    sciencedog_node:
        build: ../sciencedog/.
        container_name: sciencedog_node
        ports:
            - 80:8001
        networks:
            - sciencedog
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: /etc/sciencedog/.env
              target: /etc/sciencedog/.env
              read_only: true
            - type: bind
              source: ../sciencedog/src/.
              target: /opt/sciencedog_node/src/

    sciencedog_db:
        image: mongo:4.0.4
        container_name: sciencedog_db
        volumes:
            - sciencedog:/data/db
        networks:
            - sciencedog

volumes:
    sciencedog:
        driver: local

networks:
    sciencedog:
        driver: bridge
```

docker-compose dev extension (enables connection from host, not needed for containers to communicate via docker network):

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    sciencedog_python:
        ports:
            - 6900:6900
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true

    sciencedog_db:
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the same code is able to connect in another machine, I'll guess the problem is initialization order - when running in the dev machine, the nodejs container is starting first and trying to connect to Mongo too early.

Quick way to solve this is declaring a dependency between the nodejs container and the Mongo one:

```yaml
sciencedog_node:
    networks:
        # etc etc etc
    depends_on:
        - sciencedog_db
```

Note that even when declaring such dependencies, it's not guaranteed that Mongo will be 100% ready to receive connections (see https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/), so I think you would benefit from configuring a generous timeout for `MongoClient`:

```js
// example taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979924/how-to-set-mongoclient-connection-timeout
MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, {
    server: {
        socketOptions: {
            connectTimeoutMS: 20000
        }
    }
}).then(.....)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried both of those ideas out, but it doesn't seem to have solved the problem.