# Node.js, Disconnect to database if take more than a piece of time

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use Node.js to connect to local mongodb

I want to stop program tried to connect to mongodb, if it take more than a piece of time. (ex: 1 second or 2 seconds)
After that I want to execute other code.

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
const client = new MongoClient(url)

async function main() {
    try {
         await client.connect()  // I want to stop this line
    } catch {
         return;   
    }
}

main()
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62397872

Comment: May I ask why? Connection is asynchronous, you can execute other code while still connecting in the background.  I assume at some point you will need to connect to the database after the "other code" is finished. Otherwise there is no need to connect at the first place, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting timeout

```
const client = new MongoClient(url,{
    connectTimeoutMS: 5000,
});
```

This will throw timeout error if it takes more than 5 seconds

Comment: I tried it, I use 1000, but it still stuck over than 1 second, and then throw error

Comment: If mongo is not start, no server is provided, does this still work?